# Does English have 8,000 sounds?

Tags: word-usage, sounds

I remember hearing a few years ago that English had 8,000 different sounds, and it's something that has stuck with me this entire time. I've started to question this knowledge, since googling various search terms yields only a single non-academic result:

https://twitter.com/zschilleci/status/658649029601943552

There seem to only be '44 key sounds' in English, based on search results. This seems more correct.

There is at least one other person who seems to think that there are 8,000 sounds in the English language? If this assertion is hopelessly incorrect, where do you think this assertion comes from?

It seems to be something akin to the myth that humans only use 10% of their brain.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the number of syllables? [Here](http://listserv.linguistlist.org/pipermail/lingtyp/2004-January/001388.html) is a site which quotes somebody as saying that there are 8000 syllables in English.

Comment: Perhaps. This is the website where I originally got the idea, I believe: http://blog.zerocalvin.com/easy-peasy-japanese-pronunciation-guide/
In the context of Japanese, which consists of syllabaries, then this is most likely what is meant.

Comment: It had 8000 until just now. I added another.